# MainPageResized and ScenarioLoaded events from MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I'm studying some examples of C# from Microsoft, mainly MainPage.xaml.cs file. In that file some events called my attention: `MainPage_SizeChanged` and `Scenarios_SelectionChanged`.
Both events are registered in the constructor. Two event handlers area declared too:

```
public event System.EventHandler ScenarioLoaded;
public event EventHandler<MainPageSizeChangedEventArgs> MainPageResized;
```

They are used on these methods:

```
void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    InvalidateSize();
    if (MainPageResized != null)
    {
        MainPageSizeChangedEventArgs args = new MainPageSizeChangedEventArgs();
        args.ViewState = ApplicationView.Value;
        MainPageResized(this, args);
    }
}

void Scenarios_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Scenarios.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        NotifyUser("", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        ListBoxItem selectedListBoxItem = Scenarios.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
        SuspensionManager.SessionState["SelectedScenarioIndex"] = Scenarios.SelectedIndex;
        Scenario scenario = selectedListBoxItem.Content as Scenario;
        LoadScenario(scenario.ClassType);
        InvalidateSize();
        if (ScenarioLoaded != null)
        {
            ScenarioLoaded(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Looking in the file there's no place where the `ScenarioLoaded` and `MainPageResized` are registered. So who's responsible for the registration and where they are occured?

Comment: I'm a little unclear what exactly you're asking for.  What do you mean by "there's no place where the <events> are registered"?  Are you asking about who is subscribing to the events?  If so, then some other class would do a call of `MainPageInstance.ScenarioLoaded += OtherClass.HandlerFunction`, which may not be shown in the example code.

Comment: Correct. I'm talking about event subscribing. This is the second example provided by Microsoft that I saw and I can't find any outside class that uses these two events. Because of this I've searched carefully with files on these samples and unfortunately I found nothing. And for me it's strange an event calling another event. It's a thing I need to familiarize myself.

Comment: I'm not sure which MS example you're referring to, but it's likely in this case that they were just showing how to set this up, to keep the scope of the article focused.  Are you just wanting to know how to subscribe to events, or are you looking for something more specific about _these_ events?  If so, what are you looking for about these ones?

Comment: XAMLBasicControls and XAMLBindingData I've opened. I was looking for a place in the MainPage.xaml.cs that contains subscription for these events. Neither of them uses events mentioned. I want to see a subscription for these events. May I can find in another sample.